# awk multiple files (adding values) results not in order

Tags: bash, awk

I have many files, all having the same number of rows, all having the same values in column 1 (which I want to keep). The problem is the output changes the order.

```
cat file1.dat
Sep-12 1082
Oct-12 1377
Nov-12 1095
Dec-12 888
Jan-13 1184
Feb-13 1036
Mar-13 895
Apr-13 1207
May-13 1325
Jun-13 1147
Jul-13 1256
Aug-13 1362
Sep-13 1260

cat file2.dat
Sep-12 5185
Oct-12 5707
Nov-12 5427
Dec-12 3321
Jan-13 8093
Feb-13 6000
Mar-13 6348
Apr-13 6921
May-13 6959
Jun-13 6246
Jul-13 6634
Aug-13 6704
Sep-13 6350

.....etc
```

when I run

```
awk '{a[$1]+=$2}END{for (k in a) print k,a[k]}' dat_files/*.dat
```

I get

```
May-13 20086
Nov-12 16175
Jun-13 74138
Mar-13 16598
Jan-13 18293
Aug-13 21853
Feb-13 14831
Jul-13 20614
Sep-12 12480
Sep-13 20717
Oct-12 14099
Apr-13 23954
Dec-12 11469
```

which seems to be in no particular order (and not what I want). I would like the output to be in the same order as all the .dat files, i.e. starting with

```
Sep-12 (total)
Oct-12 (total)
Nov-12 (total)
etc...
```

I thought awk read the data in each file in order...?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Associative arrays don't preserve key insertion order.   This is true in most languages.

You can store the column name order in another array and use it to print the results.

```
awk '
    {
        s[FNR] += $2
        c[FNR] = $1
    }

    END {
        for (i=1; i <= FNR; i++)
            print c[i], s[i]
    }
' dat_files/*.dat
```

Comment: Now I'm mostly lost... where does the awk command go? What changes are necessary in it? Do I just put the above in a shell script?

Comment: That was raw awk code.  I edited it to show invocation syntax.

Comment: wow - I have a lot to learn. By the time I was done reading a paragraph about associative arrays- it was done. Thanks so much. As a seasoned noob, I have so much respect for you. Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

You can simply `sort` the output as follows:

```
awk '{a[$1]+=$2}END{for (k in a) print k,a[k]}' dat_files/*.dat | sort --key=1.5,1.6 --key=1.1,1.3M
```

This will first sort by characters 5-6 of each line (i.e. the year), then sort by characters 1-3 of each line (i.e. the month).  The `M` parameter tells sort to sort by months `Jan`, `Feb`, etc, instead of numbers.

Comment: and wow.... this answer clearly shows that there is more than one way to skin a cat..... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After you get the total, say, you name it `all.dat`. Then you can try the following

```
awk 'BEGIN {j = 0} { if (content[$1] != "" ) { content2[j $1] = $0 ; j++ ; } else { content[$1] = $0 ; }  } END { for ( i in content2 ) print i, content2[i] ; } ' file1.dat all.dat 
| sort 
| awk '{ $1="" ; print ; }'
```

This script adds an artificial column for `sort` then removes it.